# Copy non empty cells in multiple rows to next blank row in new table

Tags: copy

I have a table of client card transactions. I want to copy each transaction that exists (i.e. client no, name, payment date, payment amount) into the net blank row in a new table.

I have tried writing a VBA routine but I'm really struggling.

The main transaction table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpMQg.png)

I want to just copy the non empty transactions in each client row and paste them into a summary table, like so:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49GU2.png)

Any ideas please?

Thank you so much.

Sub CopyTransactions()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim TransactionsSheet As Worksheet

Set TransactionsSheet = Worksheets("CardPaymentsLog")

TransactionsSheet.Range("AA11:AD11").Copy
TransactionsSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'In this routine, I have only got as far as copying the first transactions for the first client in the table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just bumping this up. Any help in Excel VBA would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any ideas? The first table contains the raw table of transactions and the second table is the output I require.